# Excel subroutine to create all possible combinations from a data set excluding duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

Does anyone know a routine on how to get a data set composed by 7 columns into all possible combinations?

the combination is composed by 7 numbers like this--> 1|3|8|10|35|40|50

The routine needs to look into the first table and make a list of all possible combination excluding the duplicate numbers from the combination in the second table. Please see picture.

The table on the left contains the combination which need to be reshuffled, into the right table which contain all possible combinations.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a data set like the one below"?  Do you mean the four examples at the bottom as that leaves me wondering where 1, 2 and 4 came from in the first example; or 10, 9 and 4 in the second example?  Could you show us what you've tried as well please as a [MCVE].

Comment: Are you talking about permutations? ANd your example doe not consist of digits: _the combination is composed by 6 digits like this--> 1|3|8|10|35|40|50_

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for answering, so this first example is a combination made up of 7 digits 1,3,8,10,35,40,50. These numbers are taken by the numbers found in the table N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7, which contain a set of combination.

Comment: 10, 35, 40, 50 are not [digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit), but I am not a native speaker

Comment: Where does "1|2|3|4|5|6|7" come from?

Comment: I've attached a picture you should be able to see it.

Comment: Afraid not - pictures are blocked here, so having to go through my phone now.  For tables of figures I find https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# very helpful.

Comment: thanks storax for the edit

Comment: OK that's clear. Have you tried any code - there must be examples online of extracting combinations?

Comment: Ok Storax, a combination formed by 10 numbers. ref2digit

Comment: I did, but none does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

The number of options are 6^7 so there will be alot of cases: 279936
To get all of it, you should loop through them.
First we should find all the options. 
To generate all the possible combinations including duplicates, the probles is the same as get all the may 7 digit long numbers in base 6 ( as we have 6 number in each column)

in newer excels you can use the BASE funtion, but if you can not access it you can use this:
if you cange a code a bit you can call the value of the original table instead of the 0-5 numbers.

Then just remove duplicates.

```
Sub generateAllBase6()
Dim i As Double 'number tries
Dim n As String ' the number of item from the column 1-7

For i = 0 To 279936 - 1
n = ConvertBase10(i, "012345")
    For k = 1 To 7
        If Len(n) < k Then
            Cells(i + 2, k) = 0
        Else
            Cells(i + 2, k) = Right(Left(n, k), 1)
        End If
    Next k
Next i
End Sub


Public Function ConvertBase10(ByVal d As Double, ByVal sNewBaseDigits As String) As String
    Dim S As String, tmp As Double, i As Integer, lastI As Integer
    Dim BaseSize As Integer
    BaseSize = Len(sNewBaseDigits)
    Do While Val(d) <> 0
        tmp = d
        i = 0
        Do While tmp >= BaseSize
            i = i + 1
            tmp = tmp / BaseSize
        Loop
        If i <> lastI - 1 And lastI <> 0 Then S = S & String(lastI - i - 1, Left(sNewBaseDigits, 1)) 'get the zero digits inside the number
        tmp = Int(tmp) 'truncate decimals
        S = S + Mid(sNewBaseDigits, tmp + 1, 1)
        d = d - tmp * (BaseSize ^ i)
        lastI = i
    Loop
    S = S & String(i, Left(sNewBaseDigits, 1)) 'get the zero digits at the end of the number
    ConvertBase10 = S
End Function
```

I found the funcion here: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6604

Comment: This does not do the job.